# VisJS - Place all nodes on the same side of a central node

Tags: graph, vis.js

I am trying to dynamically build a visjs node graph that shows a bivariate relationship between a lot of nodes, and a singular hub. All nodes connect to one single large node.

The edge length is determined by some value, and the node sizes are determined by some other value.

My issue is layout. How can I set the layout such that all nodes stem from one side of the canvas? When I use the current code I get one node in the center, and then other nodes 360-degrees around it. I am trying to build so that the whole thing looks like a sunrise. Large node at one side of the screen and then all the edges moving in the same direction.

I have tried using hierarchical layout, but I need to change edge lengths as one of my variables, so this is no good.

Does anyone have a method to achieve this?

My current code:

```
// create an array with nodes
        var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
            //{id: 1, label: 'Node 1', shape: 'dot', size: 200, x: -1000, y: 0, fixed:{x: true, y: true}},
            { id: 1, label: 'Node 1' },
            { id: 2, label: 'Node 2' },
            { id: 3, label: 'Node 3' },
            { id: 4, label: 'Node 4' },
            { id: 5, label: 'Node 5' }
        ]);

        // create an array with edges
        var edges = new vis.DataSet([
            { from: 1, to: 2 },
            { from: 1, to: 3 },
            { from: 1, to: 4 },
            { from: 1, to: 5 }
        ]);

        // create a network
        var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');

        // provide the data in the vis format
        var data = {
            nodes: nodes,
            edges: edges
        };
        var options = {
            
        };

        // initialize your network!
        var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

I tried using the heirarchical layout, but since the edge length can not be changed here I can't use it. Edge length is one of my variables for nearness.

I am hoping to find a layout option to pin all nodes to one side of the originator node.